# Pressing X closes my chrome tab (MacOS)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

I noticed this recently when playing online games. Pressing the 'x' key on my keyboard closes the current tab. This is not the keyboard shortcut (command + w still works). I am on MacOS High Sierra. How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if a shortcut is enabled for your 'x' key from your Mac's settings, that would be in `Preferences→Keyboard→Shortcuts→App Shortcuts→Google Chrome` and remove it if it exists there.

Comment: Thank you for your response! There is no 'x' key shortcut. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io/) installed? I found that it was overwriting lowercase x.

If you open Vimium's options, you can add custom key mappings. I did:

```
unmap x
```